# How Can the Visibility Property Hide the MovieClip on Stage

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

When I have a movie clip on stage and assign the peoperty like:

```
mv_mc._visible = true /false
```

it either shows or hide the movie clip. What I have on the stage is just a Graphical Element and Visibility is just an property.

How does it changes the visibility.I want to know the internal details how it gets executed.

Are there any tools atlease to help out?

Comment: Are you looking for Flash "Behind the scenes" logic!?

Comment: @Mattias, Yes , I want to know how things happen during compile time as I heard about Flash Byte Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe these links can help your search:

**Flasm:**
http://flasm.sourceforge.net/

**Flash Assembler:**
http://jpauclair.net/2010/03/15/flash-asm/